# Convert SQL query to SQL functions?

Tags: sql-server, function

I'm working on SQL functions

I create a query and query successful run but I wan to convert them SQL functions

I'm returning two parameter in query days and years

I want to convert SQL query to SQL function see below image

[image]

sql query

```
    Declare @dateofbirth datetime  
    Declare @currentdatetime datetime  
    Declare @years varchar(4)  
    Declare @days varchar(4)  
    set @dateofbirth = '2020-01-25 ' 
    set @currentdatetime  = getdate()   
    select @years = datediff(year,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)    
    select @days = datediff(DAY,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)
    select @years   + ' years,'  
    select @days   + ' days,'
```

**can I use Multi-statement table-valued functions (MSTVF) because my query return multiple parameter days and years**?

3 function available in ssms

- table-valued functions

  - new inline table valued function
  - scalar multi statement table valued function
- scalar-valued functions
- aggregate functions

I am not sure which function should be use?

I want to convert SQL query to SQL function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Scalar Function to achieve this.

But you have to use the `CONCAT` function at the output, there is no other option to return multi select query in function.

You can also use Table Valued function to get the output in Table format.

```
CREATE Function dbo.Years_Days(@dateofbirth datetime, @currentdatetime datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    Declare @years varchar(4)  
    Declare @days varchar(4)  

    set @currentdatetime  = ISNULL(@currentdatetime,getdate());
    select @years = datediff(year,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)    
    select @days = datediff(DAY,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)

    RETURN  @years   + ' years,' + @days   + ' days,'
END


SELECT dbo.Years_Days(  '2020-01-25 ', NULL);
```

The type of function depends on the **Return Data Type**

If the returned datatype is a Table then it needs to be a Table-Valued Function.

Further, click below link:

[Functions In SQL Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/function-operation-in-sql-database/)